# Keeping used relations (i.e., member relations) when using --tag-filter in Osmosis?

Tags: openstreetmap, filter, osmosis

I just got started with the OpenStreetMap and their OSM-files. I am using Osmosis (https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) to filter a `.osm` file. I noticed that used relations are not included in the output file (even if the relation using the other relation passes the filter). A simple example shows my problem.

As input I use a file of the city of `Nuernberg`, `Germany`. Which contains among others the following relation:

```
  <relation id="90120" version="29" timestamp="2016-11-14T01:39:24Z" uid="70621" user="BikeMap" changeset="18682819">
    <member type="relation" ref="2841" role=""/>
    <member type="relation" ref="149983" role=""/>
    <member type="relation" ref="155413" role=""/>
    <member type="relation" ref="4584" role=""/>
    <member type="relation" ref="153573" role=""/>
    <member type="relation" ref="149984" role=""/>
    <member type="relation" ref="144703" role=""/>
    <member type="relation" ref="3306" role=""/>
    <member type="relation" ref="62076" role=""/>
    <tag k="ref" v="5F"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Fünf-Flüsse-Radweg"/>
    <tag k="note" v="Bitte hier keine Members mehr hinzufügen. Dies gilt jetzt nur noch als &quot;collection&quot;"/>
    <tag k="type" v="collection"/>
    <tag k="symbol" v="5 blaue Wellen auf weisse Grund"/>
    <tag k="network" v="rcn"/>
    <tag k="operator" v="Tourismusverband Ostbayern"/>
    <tag k="wikipedia" v="de:5-Flüsse-Radweg"/>
    <tag k="collection" v="route"/>
    <tag k="description" v="[BNF 80001] Gesamter Fünf-Flüsse-Weg nach berarbeitng 2009 Nürnberg Neumarkt Regensburg Amberg Hersbruck"/>
  </relation>
```

The other relations (which are referenced) are also included in the file, e.g.,

```
  <relation id="2841" version="838" timestamp="2016-11-14T01:39:24Z" uid="2073275" user="Fredie" changeset="42609012">
    <member type="way" ref="29567066" role=""/>
    <member type="way" ref="37777855" role=""/>
    ...
```

When I run the following osmosis process:

```
--read-xml enableDateParsing=no file=/downloads/osmosis-latest/nuernberg.osm 
--tf accept-relations name=Fünf-Flüsse-Radweg
--used-way
--used-node
--write-xml file=./radweg.osm
```

The output only contains the one filtered relation (but not the members):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="Osmosis 0.45">
  <bounds minlon="10.93510" minlat="49.38660" maxlon="11.20100" maxlat="49.51380" origin="http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6"/>
  <relation id="90120" version="29" timestamp="2016-11-15T03:10:52Z" uid="70621" user="BikeMap" changeset="18682819">
    <member type="relation" ref="2841" role=""/>
    <member type="relation" ref="149983" role=""/>
    <member type="relation" ref="155413" role=""/>
    <member type="relation" ref="4584" role=""/>
    <member type="relation" ref="153573" role=""/>
    <member type="relation" ref="149984" role=""/>
    <member type="relation" ref="144703" role=""/>
    <member type="relation" ref="3306" role=""/>
    <member type="relation" ref="62076" role=""/>
    <tag k="ref" v="5F"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Fünf-Flüsse-Radweg"/>
    <tag k="note" v="Bitte hier keine Members mehr hinzufügen. Dies gilt jetzt nur noch als &quot;collection&quot;"/>
    <tag k="type" v="collection"/>
    <tag k="symbol" v="5 blaue Wellen auf weisse Grund"/>
    <tag k="network" v="rcn"/>
    <tag k="operator" v="Tourismusverband Ostbayern"/>
    <tag k="wikipedia" v="de:5-Flüsse-Radweg"/>
    <tag k="collection" v="route"/>
    <tag k="description" v="[BNF 80001] Gesamter Fünf-Flüsse-Weg nach berarbeitng 2009 Nürnberg Neumarkt Regensburg Amberg Hersbruck"/>
  </relation>
</osm>
```

How can I include all the other needed relations?

Is there something like `--used-way (--uw)` or `--used-node (--un)` for relations?

If not, is there any documentation on how to implement own filters?